# How to find the difference of x -y using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, difference

As you see in the code, I want to find the difference of `x-y` using the resulting `R` of `solve`. But, the code keeps returning `x-y` as value. Please help me. I am a 10 year old kid that just started coding.

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols ('x, y')
eq1 = sp.Eq(7 * x, 12 * y)
eq2 = sp.Eq(x+y, 9500)
R = sp.solve ((eq1, eq2), (x, y))
print (x-y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result `R` of sp.solve is a Python dictionary with values for `x` and for `y`:

```py
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x, y')
eq1 = sp.Eq(7 * x, 12 * y)
eq2 = sp.Eq(x + y, 9500)
R = sp.solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y))
```

Result: `{x: 6000, y: 3500}`

To apply the resulting dictionary to an expression, use `subs(R)`:

```py
print((x - y).subs(R))
```

Result: `2500`